# How to pass constructor parameters to a contract using Truffle?

Tags: contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp, truffle, testrpc

I am using testrpc and truffle for deploying contracts.I want to pass constructor parameters while deploying.

```
    contract User { 
          string public userName;

          function User(string _name) {
                 userName=_name;
          }

   }
```

I am using contractname.deployed() for deploying contract.

```
      var user=User.deployed()
```

This deployment command won't initializes the userName parameter.

How to pass _name to this contract using truffle?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Truffle, constructor params go in /migrations. So, something like:

```
deployer.deploy(User, "foo");
```

`User.deployed()` will be a User contract that was deployed with _name="foo"

Comment: There should be a way to create a contract with different constructor parameters, no ?

Comment: Sure. This line, `function User(string _name)` defines one parameter for the constructor. There could be more or different parameters.

Comment: I meant creating the contract with other paramters, not just modifying the variables. I have a contract that sets ownership of contract at construction to an address passed in argument. Only the owner of the contract will afterwards be able to change contract data. If I call deploy now, it sets the owner address to 0. I understood from your answer that I can change that from migrations but setting a value to my parameter. But that means I can create contracts with the same owner everytime, I would like to be able to modify the arguments from truffle console

Comment: Something like owner would usually be a non-random address, e.g. another contract or user. Migration scripts are JavaScript. You can interrogate a function in an unrelated contract to acquire the correct value, then pass it in. Really, any way you want to establish the correct address is fine, then pass it in. I wonder if you're after a factory pattern. That is, deploy a contract and then use a function in the contract to deploy something else with the factory conveniently becoming owner. Maybe ... https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/is-there-a-simple-contract-factory-pattern

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider the test contract in which the constructor accepts two params:

```csharp
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract Test {
    address public owner;
    address public user1;
    address public user2;

    constructor (address _user1, address _user2)  {
        owner = msg.sender;
        user1 = _user1;
        user2 = _user2;
    }
}
```

Truffle-test will use [MyContract.new([arg1, arg2, ...], [tx params])](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#-code-mycontract-new-arg1-arg2-tx-params-code-) to pass params to the constructor:

```js
const TestContract = artifacts.require('Test');

contract('Test', function (accounts) {
    const [owner, user1, user2] = accounts;
    const txParams = { from: owner };

    beforeEach(async function () {
        this.testContract = await TestContract.new(user1, user2, txParams);
    });

    it('has an owner, user1 and user2', async function () {
        expect(await this.testContract.owner()).to.equal(owner);
        expect(await this.testContract.user1()).to.equal(user1);
        expect(await this.testContract.user2()).to.equal(user2);
    });
});
```

Take into account that to access to state-variable is used the [getter-function](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#getter-functions).