# Deploy contract from contract in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

It's a common pattern to use a hub/factory contract to create multiple instances of a standard contract.

It's also common to require a way to enumerate the addresses of the created contracts.

Is there a simple minimal example of a good approach?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a simple hub (Bakery) that deploys contracts (Cookie) from a template and keeps track of the contracts created.

Note that `Cookie` is part of the source file so `Bakery` can "see it" during compilation. `Cookie`'s ByteCode will become part of Bakery so the `new Cookie()` invocation knows what to do.

Deploy the hub/factory (`Bakery`). It's not necessary to deploy the template (`Cookie`). You can create as many of the latter as needed by calling a function in the former.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Bakery {

  // index of created contracts

  address[] public contracts;

  // useful to know the row count in contracts index

  function getContractCount() 
    public
    constant
    returns(uint contractCount)
  {
    return contracts.length;
  }

  // deploy a new contract

  function newCookie()
    public
    returns(address newContract)
  {
    Cookie c = new Cookie();
    contracts.push(c);
    return c;
  }
}


contract Cookie {

  // suppose the deployed contract has a purpose

  function getFlavor()
    public
    constant
    returns (string flavor)
  {
    return "mmm ... chocolate chip";
  }    
}
```

If you need more functionality in the index (e.g. is 0x123 a contract?) consider more feature-complete storage patterns: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Hope it helps.

Comment: For 5 seconds I was confused by the erroneous thought that an Ethereum contract could be identified via an HTTP protocol cookie. In classic OO programming terms your Bakery is a singleton factory and the method newCookie() creates a new instance of a contract of type Cookie.

Comment: @Rob are there any concerns with the contracts array getting very large (say, millions or tens-of-millions addresses)?

Comment: Its economically constrained, not technically constrained. The pattern will scale as large as one can afford to pay for writes. The key thing is the gas cost is consistent at any scale.

Comment: I don't understand the type paradigm here. How come `c` is both a `Cookie` and an `address`? It's created as the former but stored in an array (and returned) as the latter. Why isn't `contracts` an array of `Cookie[]` instead of `address[]`?

Comment: Good questions. Q1: c is a Cookie, which is a contract and contracts are directly convertible to addresses. The newer compiler wants to see that explicitly, like `return address(c);`. We're using an array of address as a list of keys we can use to discover the rest which is more economical than an array of large objects.

Comment: why am i mad that this bakery only sells chocolate chip cookies

Comment: Because, scope creep?

Comment: The return value with the new contract address on newCookie() can't be accessed by the caller though right? The function will be a transaction call which will result in a receipt object.

Comment: `getFlavor()` is `constant` (would be `pure1 now) so the return value is easily accessible.

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab So I had a question here. It is creating and storing addresses of new contract instances but my question is how do you access a method inside your instance contract (cookie) . Like say I have stored some data in that cookie then how do I retrieve that data later on.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing the method I created a new function and did it like this

```
function getCookieFlavor(address cookie) public view returns(string){
    return Cookie(cookie).getFlavor();
}
```

just pass in the address of the cookie which is already created.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, one can access the deployed contracts (the Cookies) directly if they have the ABI (either JSON ABI or an Interface), and they know the address of the instance, which they can get from the Hub.