# Is it possible to verify multiple accounts' attached main parent user?

Tags: go-ethereum

**[Q]** Is there any unique ID for `geth` or `parity` usage, which might help use to detect multiple created accounts' main parent creator? (I assume all those multiple accounts are created by the same main user, using the same geth node).

For example, using a `geth` or `parity` node same user can create multiple accounts which are attach to actually one user. If there is unique geth or parity ID, maybe that might help us the identify all created accounts are actually attach to one user using the linked to the same geth or parity node where accounts are created.

Another example: we wrote contracts for voting using `msg.sender` for voters. I realise that a user can create many dummy users, which he could use them to vote for himself. We cannot prevent this from happening since each ethereum account is different from each other.

```
       function becomeMemberCandidate(bytes32 ipfsHash) public
        not_member returns(bool) {

        members[msg.sender] = uint32(membersInfo.length); //contains addresses which can vote within the contract.
        memberAddresses.push( msg.sender ); 
        return true; 
    }
```

Comment: "I realise that a user can create many dummy users" ...for voting, each user must pay some gas however

Comment: But Gas payment would be not that much around 30,000. and if the user will gain a fund by the voting number like a winner he can keep vote for himself with dummy accounts of his. @NineCattoRules

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be desirable to be able to link multiple externally owned accounts to a single user, or to a single node, for reasons of privacy.

From the perspective of *contract* accounts, you could have a look at a general factory pattern, whereby a parent factory contract could create multiple identical child contracts. The creation of the child contracts could then be traced to the parent, and so on.

See: [Is There a Simple Contract Factory Pattern?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/is-there-a-simple-contract-factory-pattern)

Comment: Well I am doing is but on the factory pattern example, when ever newCookie() is called similiarly I do newMember() , but as new member since anyone could register itself as a member, a user can create 100s of new member which could vote for himself. @Richard Horrocks