# How exactly can we deploy a contract on a button click from a front end when we are using nodejs and running testrpc?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I want to deploy my contract by taking in parameters from the webpage and they serve as parameters for my contract's constructor and when I click on a button I should be able to deploy the contract on testrpc

Answer (score 1):

You can use a factory pattern contract like this: [Is There a Simple Contract Factory Pattern?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/is-there-a-simple-contract-factory-pattern)

Connect a button in the UI to your `newContract()` factory function.

*In my estimation*, this is preferable to a client-side compile because it provides assurance that the deployed contract is an exact replica of the factory's template.

Hope it helps.