# How to access Objects from different Contracts

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct, inheritance

**Goal**: I want to create a solidity programm that includes 3+ contracts. This means I have one contract (lets call it master for now) which aims at setting everything up. This means this contract has a function that ask for addresses of contracts that should interact with each other. The master stores this address information and can later pass it to other contracts. I will have 3+ other contracts that get this "contact information" from the Master contract and then those 3+ start interacting with each other(Changing other variables, calling functions of other contracts)

**Example**: 
Contract has a Setup-Function that asks for addresses of contracts A and B. He stores those addresses and calls Function 1 of contract A. Now Function 1 of contract A does some stuff, then looks up the address of Contract B (this is where I struggle) and calls Function 2 which belongs to Contract B.

**Question**: Can somebody help me with this question and give me some example code? I already tried passing a struct with the addresses from the Master to A and B, tried to store them in a mapping and tried to make my Master contracts data accessible to A and B via inheritance.

If you have any trouble understanding this question feel free to ask ;)

Answer (score 2):

Owing to time constraints I can answer indirectly with a (hopefully) clear pattern.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract A {

    function talkToMe() public constant returns(bool success) {
        return true;
    }
}

contract B {

    A a; // contract "A" called "a"

    event LogResponse(bool whatItSaid);

    function B() {
        a = new A(); // deploy B and it will make it's own A and note the address
    }

    function prove() public returns(bool success) {
        bool response = a.talkToMe();
        LogResponse(response);
        return response;
    }

    function newA(address addressA) public returns(bool success) {
        a = A(addressA); // start using previously deployed A 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here it is Remix to show it working.

1. Deploy B
2. `prove()`

[image]

This answer addresses some more concerns like keeping track of the contracts generated by the "factory". [Is There a Simple Contract Factory Pattern?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/is-there-a-simple-contract-factory-pattern)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I know the pattern you gave me is working cause that is basically what I already have :) I guess I was not clear in that regard, which is my bad! I ll try to insert an Image of my code to show what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Above you can see my Code. It uses the pattern you have already shown me and works fine! All contracts can interact. Now I want to clean this up a little. I highlighted the things I want to change in yellow.

For my it would be cool to extract all the "yellow-stuff" from contract 'ObjA' into to put it in the 'masterObj' contract. So I like to create something like an array/mapping where I put in all the contracts (let's say 'a' which then refers to the concrete ObjA contract) and then If I interact with some contract I just pass this array/mapping and then it can read the contract address of all other contracts from this array/mapping.

So basically I want to have only "computations" in contracts A to Z and everything else that is administration in the masterObj contract. Do you have any Idea how to realize this?
I hope my question gets clearer now :) 
And Thanks a lot for your time by the way!