# Creating Contract instances from contract methods

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-debugging, nethereum

I've been working on the concept of building a MUD type game using Blockchain as the data storage.
Note - this is a private network - so ether cost is not really a huge issue for me.

Given a contract that looks like this:

```
contract EtherWorldStorage {
    /* Constructor */
    address owner;
    mapping (bytes32 => World) Gameworlds;

    mapping (bytes32 => uint) NamesIndex;
    World[] worldContracts;

    function EtherWorldStorage(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }


    event WorldCreated(bytes32 indexed worldName, address indexed sender, address result );

    function createWorld(bytes32 name) returns (address a){
        if(NamesIndex[name] > 0x0){
            return 0x0;
        }
        World w = new World(name);
        NamesIndex[name] = worldContracts.length - 1;
        Gameworlds[name] = w;
        WorldCreated(name,msg.sender,w);
        return w;
    }

  function getWorldCount() returns (uint i){
        return worldContracts.length;
    }

    function destroyWorld(bytes32 world){

        World w = Gameworlds[world];
        w.destroy(owner);
    }


function getItemPossessorsInventory(InventoryItem item) returns (address a){
        return item.getOwningInventory();
    }

}
```

When I call the createWorld function from nethereum - I can see the transaction going in, I wait for the mining to complete, but my event is never fired?

Is what I am doing to complex for ethereum?
Note - the World contract then instantiates an Area contract, which then instantiates a Door object.

I am estimating the gas price by nethereums
var callResult = f.EstimateGasAsync(args).Result;

Where f is the function call.

My .Net code in nethereum looks like this:

```
public static string CreateWorld(string world)
        {
            var web3 = new Web3(Resources.Server);
            var result = web3.Personal.UnlockAccount.SendRequestAsync("0x54a222aE3d59EF92D715409f31C6eCAf331D0782", Resources.Password, 30).Result;
            if (result != true)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to unlock account...");
            }




            var d = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(world);


            string address = "0x30d578718e1da379f4B1B1ac5E9be9ba646E0bCF"; // Contract address
            var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(Resources.ContractInterface2, address);

            var add = contract.GetFunction("createWorld");                         // Add method
            var worldCreatedEvent= contract.GetEvent("WorldCreated");
            var filterAll = worldCreatedEvent.CreateFilterAsync().Result;
            var totalGas = new HexBigInteger(GetGasPrice(add, d).Value*2);

            HexBigInteger gasPrice = new HexBigInteger(new BigInteger(0.144));

            var callResult = add.SendTransactionAsync("0x54a222aE3d59EF92D715409f31C6eCAf331D0782", totalGas,new HexBigInteger(0), d);
            var theResult = GetReceiptAsync(web3, callResult.Result);
            var log = worldCreatedEvent.GetAllChanges<dynamic>(filterAll).Result;


            return log[0].Event;
            return callResult.Result;
        }
```

No matter what, my log always ends up with 0 elements in it, and even using Ethereum Wallet - I don't see any contract events being raised.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it sorted- I think I was calling GetAllChanges on the function instead of the event.

In any case- I can see the events being raised now.
I added in

```
event RequestReceived(string s);
```

So I could track how far in the contract functions the execution was getting to.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, there is a pattern over here: [Is There a Simple Contract Factory Pattern?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/is-there-a-simple-contract-factory-pattern)

I think you'll find more clarity by focusing on the data structure first. This "factory" will make Worlds, so all that's required is an index to the Worlds (and events, etc.)

```
address[] public worldList;
```

You can build the index as you go:

```
World newWorld = new World(name);
return worldList.push(newWorld);
```

To support your delete function, you will need to know which row in worldList each World address lives on, so modify the mapping slightly:

```
mapping(address => uint) worldPointer;
```

and modify the new world process slightly:

```
worldPointer[newWorld] = worldList.push(newWorld) - 1; // because it returns the array length
```

That way, `worldPointer[world]` will give you the row to delete from `worldList` when you destroy a world.

There's a more complete explanation of a proper delete from an arbitrary row in an array over here: https://medium.com/@robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-2-ed8d8b4f74ec

Hope it helps.