# Capture events from a state variable which is a contract

Tags: solidity, events, truffle-contract

I developed a contract which uses another contract in it state variable, but looks like the events from the contract in the state variable aren’t dispatched.

```
contract A {
  event Hello(uint num);
  function doSomething() {
   Hello(1);
  }
}

contract B {
  A public a;

  function doAnotherThing() public {
    a = new A();
    a.doSomething();
  }
}
```

What is expected: To be possible to capture the events from the `contract A` which is a state variable in the contract `B`. So when call `a.doSomething()` in the contract `B` should be dispatched the event `Hello(1)` and be possible to capture in the `watch`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're confusing inheritance with deployment.

Your `contract B` deploys a new instance of `contract A`. `contract A` has an event emitter and a function `doSomething()` and you can invoke it directly with `addressA.dosomething()` or indirectly with `addressB.doSomethingElse()`. In either case, you can listen to events from `contractA` but `contractB` will not emit events.

This would be an entirely different picture in the case of inheritance.

You could say:

`contract B is A { ...}`

In this case, you would be able to invoke `addressB.doSomething()` and listen for the event at `addressB` because all of `A` would become part of `B`.  You would drop the references to `A` as an external thing in that case.

```
contract B is A {
  // A public a;

  function doAnotherThing() public {
    // a = new A();
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Rob, but I'm not confusing I think, looks like the `events` are tied to the contract which has an `address` and is called in a transaction so they generate events, but the state variable can't generate event because isn't called directly in the transaction. I'm not sure if I'm totally right about that, but now it makes more sense to me.

Comment: `contract A` has an address, too. You can do `event LogNewA(address newContract)` ... `LogNewA(a);` and see the address in B's event log.

Comment: For sure, when it runs the `a = new A()` the state variable `a` will receive an `address` too :) is possible to watch that variable by his `address`, right ?

Comment: `a` is cast as contract `A` which is directly convertible to type `address`. You might find some inspiration with the pattern laid out over here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/is-there-a-simple-contract-factory-pattern

Answer (score 0):

The events are triggered and recorded in the transaction receipt. In your case what is failing is that the source of the events is not the contract B, but contract A.

A new instance of contrac A is created before calling `a.doSomething()`, that will be the source of the event.