# Truffle - call migration file multiple times

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, factory

I would like to execute migration file "6_deploy_and_register_group.js" every time when I need to create a new group. 
Is this a proper way to use migrations? 
If yes, how can I make it working? Calling:

```
truffle migrate 6_deploy_and_register_group.js
```

gives me that "network is up to date". Is there any way to execute only that file but have stored other addresses unchanged?

2_deploy_registry.js:

```
var Registry = artifacts.require('./Registry');

module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts)
{
    await deployer.deploy(Registry);
};
```

6_deploy_and_register_group.js:

```
var Group = artifacts.require('./Group');
var Registry = artifacts.require('./Registry');

const args = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts)
{
    let units = args["itemscount"];
    if(units == null)
    {
        console.log('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'did you forget to use --itemscount=xyz argument?');
    }
    let groupName = args["groupname"];
    if(groupName == null)
    {
        console.log('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'did you forget to use --groupname=xyz argument?');
    }
    await deployer.deploy(Group, groupName, units);
    let registry = await Registry.deployed();
    await registry.register(Group.address);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a good use of migrations.

Migrations are about deploying the system to the network and one-time initialization steps. This function seems to be about operations - creating instances of `Groups` and registering them in the `Registry`.

It's unclear but likely that this process should be restricted to an authorized admin user or minimally there should be an assurance that the registered contract is indeed a Group and not merely a random address. Some protections are needed here to avoid chaos and an off-chain approach won't provide that assurance.

*In my opinion*, a default approach is to severely limit what is acceptable.

1. A Registry that only accepts legitimate Group contracts. One approach would be to restrict it to only listen to a trusted Factory contract.
2. A Factory that only lets authorized user deploy a new Group and attends to the registration.

A factory contract would ensure that deployed Group contracts are built from the same template. Here is a very skeletal sketch to give you some ideas:

**Factory.sol**

```
import "./Group.sol";
import "./RegistryInterface.sol";

contract GroupFactory is Owned {

  RegistryInterface r;

  function setRegistry(address reg) public onlyOwner {
    r = RegistryInterface(reg);
  }

  function createAndRegisterGroup(bytes32 groupName, uint units) public onlyOwner {
    Group g = new Group(groupName, units);
    r.registerGroup(address(g));
  }
```

**Registry.sol**

```
address public factory;
address[] public groupList;

modifier onlyFactory {
  require(msg.sender == factory);
  _;
}

function setFactory(address _factory) public onlyOwner {
  factory = _factory;
}

function registerGroup(address group) public onlyFactory {
  groupList.push(group);
}
```

Above is a very simplistic sketch with simple access control restrictions. You would deploy a Registry once and a factory once. Following deployment, you would rely on the factory to deploy new Groups. There is some more discussion on Factory contracts over here: [Deploy contract from contract in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/deploy-contract-from-contract-in-solidity/13416#13416)

The `migrations` would be concerned with the initial deployment as well as the configuration steps - setting the Factory address in the Registry and setting the Registry address in the Factory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. If I use factory in migration or test I can't get the result address of factory built. I can't return address of newly created group because it returns the hash. Watching event doesn't work in migration or test, tried on google but none is working.

Comment: You can use factories in tests and migrations, you can get the address of the contracts created by a factory, you can watch events. Those are candidates for new questions so this thread stays focused on a single question.