# Deploying a Contract from a Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment

I'm new to Solidity and the whole blockchain environment. Learning it from a course.

I have been assigned a task which is to:

> Make a parent contract that has the ability to deploy child contracts.

Can someone please guide or refer me to some resource that can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For create a new instance of contract you must to use the word 'new' and the name of the contract like:

```
[NameContract] contract = new [NameContract]();
```

With this statement you could use it to create a new child contract in a `function` or in parent contract's `constructor`.
See this example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract ParentContract {
    // State variable ParentContract
    ChildContract private child;

    constructor() {
        // Create a new Child contract 
        child = new ChildContract("Test", 30);
    }
}

contract ChildContract {
    // State variables Child contract
    string name;
    uint age;

    constructor(string memory _name, uint _age) {
        name = _name;
        age = _age;
    }
}
```

If you want more details, see [here](https://medium.com/upstate-interactive/creating-a-contract-with-a-smart-contract-bdb67c5c8595).

Answer (score 0):

[Deploy contract from contract in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13415/deploy-contract-from-contract-in-solidity)

Should be lots of answers in here, but just know the basic format, where contract B is a contract:

```
  function newB()
    public
    returns(address newContract)
  {
    B b = new B();
    return b;
  }
```