# Accessing testrpc addresses from solidity tests

Tags: contract-development, truffle, testrpc, testing

I'm consulting truffle's docs on how to test contracts directly in solidity.

http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/solidity-tests

I'd like to figure out a way to refer to existing testrpc accounts in my tests. Something like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/BAToken.sol";

contract TestBAToken {
  function testNewBATokenNotFinalized() {
    address companyFundAddress = addresses[1];  // <-- I'd like this to be a predefined testrpc account
    address userFundAddress = addresses[2];
    uint256 startBlock = block.number - 100;
    uint256 endBlock = block.number + 100;
    BAToken ba = new BAToken(companyFundAddress, userFundAddress, startBlock, endBlock);
    Assert.equal(ba.isFinalized, false, "Token sale shouldn't be finalized upon initialization.");
  }
}
```

Is this possible? If not, anyone have any good recommendations for how to refer to existing accounts during testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly add the addresses in the solidity contract instead of `addresses[1]` and `addresses[2]`. If you do not want to do that, then you can declare some variables in the contract for the addresses and intialize them as part of the constructor as shown below.

```
contract TestBAToken {
  address companyFundAddress;
  address userFundAddress;
  function TestBAToken(address address1, address address2) {
    companyFundAddress = address1;
    userFundAddress = address2;
  }
  function testNewBATokenNotFinalized() {
    uint256 startBlock = block.number - 100;
    uint256 endBlock = block.number + 100;
    BAToken ba = new BAToken(companyFundAddress, userFundAddress, startBlock, endBlock);
    Assert.equal(ba.isFinalized, false, "Token sale shouldn't be finalized upon initialization.");
  }
}
```

If you want the declare the addresses inside that function only rather than the complete contract. You can pass them as arguments for `testNewBATokenNotFinalized` function.

The way to implement depends on how you would like the contract to be and what it should do.

Comment: Thanks, but what addresses would the caller use? Just any hard-coded value?

Comment: It depends on what companyFundAddress and userFundAddress you want to set for the new BAToken you are creating.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that my tests are usually running in the context of the testrpc network, which generates a set of ten accounts with ETH in them to test with. I need to somehow inject this context into many of my non-trivial tests for them to work. How do I do this when solidity has no awareness of the testrpc accounts?

Comment: You can pass the account addresses as part of the contract constructor. As you can see constructor here has 2 parameters address1 and address2 which can be initialized. You can refer to this, to know how to deploy contracts in truffle with constructor parameters. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10830/how-to-pass-constructor-parameters-to-a-contract-using-truffle