# How can I deploy a smart contract via URL?

Tags: contract-deployment, json-rpc

I want to deploy a smart contract via curl and send parameters in the constructor, I found this [example](https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/contracts-and-transactions/accessing-contracts-and-transactions.rst) but he does not send parameters, thankyou!!

Comment: do you curl or url?

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean by "deploy by URL"? Do you mean deploy a smart contract through a web app interface, like `"http://localhost:3000/deploy?param1='blah'&param2='blah2'`? Or are you trying to use the RPC interface running locally at `http://localhost:8545` to deploy a contract?

Comment: Sorry I want to deploy via curl with the RPC interface running locally

Answer (score 1):

There are only two methods of deploying smart contracts with parameters. You either use [Truffle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10830/how-to-pass-constructor-parameters-to-a-contract-using-truffle?rq=1) or [Geth via a locally running RPC enabled node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/deploying-contract-with-constructor-arguments-via-geth-rpc?rq=1).

However, I imagine there are web API's out there to deploy smart contracts using a node running on a remote server. That would *technically* qualify as deploying smart contracts via URL. I don't know of any though.

Comment: OP specified in comments a wish to deploy via a locally running RPC.